# Ask About this Error : Type Error: Can't mix string and bytes in path components

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, typeerror, pafy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpgsy.png)I make Download GUI Program with PyQt5 that download video from youtube, I use pafy modules in my code , the problem is when i Convert the script to exe file  the gui appear but the program not responding when i press on button to begin download , the program not responding and close,and this error apear on cmd "Type Error: Can't mix string and bytes in path components " , this is my code that i use ,

I Use win10 and python3.6.

```
class threading_one(QThread, QMessageBox):
    signal = pyqtSignal()
    count_pro = pyqtSignal(int)
    cha_name = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def progress_count(self, total, recvd, ratio, rate, eta):
        read_data = recvd
        if total > 0:
            download_percentage = read_data * 100 / total
            self.count_pro.emit(download_percentage)
            if download_percentage >= 100:
                self.signal.emit()

    def run(self):

        video = pafy.new(self.url)
        stream = video.getbest(preftype='mp4')
        self.cha_name.emit(video.title)
        stream.download(filepath=self.save, callback=self.progress_count)
        self.signal.emit()


class MainApp(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Handel_Screen()
        self.Handel_Button()

    def Handel_Screen(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Test Download Program")

    def Handel_Button(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.download_video)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.Browse_Location)

        self.down_single = threading_one()
        self.down_single.signal.connect(self.finish)
        self.down_single.count_pro.connect(self.chang_progressBar)
        self.down_single.cha_name.connect(self.change_name_video)

    def chang_progressBar(self, value):
        self.progressBar.setValue(value)

    def finish(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Complete Download ...", "Your Download is Complete ...")
        self.lineEdit.clear()
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)

    def Browse_Location(self):
        save_lacation = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select Location')
        self.label.setText(save_lacation)

    def change_name_video(self, title):
        self.label_2.setText(title)

    def download_video(self):
        self.down_single.url = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.down_single.save = self.label.text()

        if self.lineEdit.text() == "":
            QMessageBox.warning(self, " From System ! ", " Please put valid URL first  !! ")
            return
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.down_single.start()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the Error:

```
C:\Users\Amr\PycharmProjects\test1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Amr/PycharmProjects/test1/index.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Amr/PycharmProjects/test1/index.py", line 42, in run
        stream.download(filepath=self.save, callback=self.progress_count)
      File "C:\Users\Amr\PycharmProjects\test1\venv\lib\site-packages\pafy\backend_shared.py", line 587, in download
        filepath = os.path.join(savedir, filename)
      File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ntpath.py", line 115, in join
        genericpath._check_arg_types('join', path, *paths)
      File "C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\genericpath.py", line 151, in _check_arg_types
        raise TypeError("Can't mix strings and bytes in path components") from None
    TypeError: Can't mix strings and bytes in path components

    Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Comment: Can you include the full traceback and info on how self.saveing is set?

Comment: I update my all code now , really i need your help

Comment: Can you post the full text of the TypeError too? Somewhere you are getting bytes instead of an encoded string, maybe in `self.save`. You can try `stream.download(filepath=self.save.decode('utf-8'), callback=self.progress_count)`

Comment: I put Error Photo now K you can see it

Comment: @AmrAntarIsmaiel So what is the full traceback when you use: `stream.download(filepath=self.save, callback=self.progress_count)`? And what is the output of `print(repr(self.save))`?

Comment: Not 100% sure where the mixup is happening - as suggested above if you could print(self.save) and print(type(self.save)) that would help. Looks like pafy generates a temporary filename if only a directory is provided for filepath so perhaps they have a bug in their windows implementation.

Comment: @AmrAntarIsmaiel What are you using to convert the script to an exe file? Do you **only** see the error after you convert to an exe file?

Comment: @ekhumoro  I Use Pyinstaller and Py to exe  and setup.py file ,  but no way my frind

Comment: @AmrAntarIsmaiel Please answer all the other questions you were asked in the comments, otherwise we cannot help you.